# Why are house helpers so expensive in the west?

Tags: microeconomics

In India, unlike western countries, most families employed in formal sector can afford a maid (engineer, doctor and so on). The commonly quoted reason on why one can do this is because of the large income inequality in India.

I notice that this is also the case with middle eastern countries like Kuwait, Saudi, Dubai and so on. However, the reason why the people there can be do this maybe due to being very rich from oil money.

However, in the west, those with same jobs won't be able to afford any such househelpers normally.

I want to ask why that's the case when there still unemployement (albeit much lower there too). Wouldn't it be better for a person to become a househelper than to be poor on the streets or so?

Comment: "*However, the reason why the people there can be do this maybe due to being very rich from oil money.*" No, the reason is that there is crazy income inequality in these oil rich monarchies? Have you not heard about this?

Comment: Normally income inequality we speak in the natives of population itself. I don't think one would say income inequality inside native of the ME itself, but sure, there is one between them and third world. That's the case with any country much more developed than another  tho. @Giskard